# Inbound rules : Azure ML endpoint to Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, inbound-security-rule, azure-promptflow

I created an Azure Machine Learning online deployment with a prompt flow that utilizes a connection to a SQL Server hosted on an Azure VM (different region and resource group). I need to configure security inbound rule to allow the Azure Machine Learning endpoint to access VM. Since the endpoint uses a dynamic IP address, how can I implement the appropriate network security configurations to enable secure communication between the two resources?

Tried to add AzureMachineLearning and AzureMachineLearningInference service tags but it does not work